# AWS (Amazon Web Services) automatic file partitioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a questions regarding AWS(Amazon Web Services). Suppose I host 1 GB of data( of say, a game) on AWS, and give my users an installer file which downloads the 1 GB data from AWS. This 1 GB can be divided into, say 4 parts of 250 mb each. If I add another segment of, say 1 mb and increase the partitions to 5, will AWS acutmatically divide the 1GB of data equally among the 5 partitions(200 MB each). How will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to do some research on the different type of storage services on AWS. This is a big topic with lots of different aspects (Like money, speed, reliability, etc.)

Also hard to say what is your exact goal. If your goal is to dynamically allocate your storage capacity, provide a cheap but fast and reliable source for your installers then the general answer for you is S3.
This is a block storage, great to store big files, pay what you use, you can put a CDN (AWS Cloudfront) front of it. You are able to do different way of authentication to prevent everyone downloading your files. There is a file size limit of 5TB, but unlimited number of files.
It is redundant and HA.

Other solutions like EBS volumes or the future EFS services are significantly more expensive, but you get a real filesystem with them. ( But I feel you don't need all of those.)

[AWS Storage options](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Storage_Options.pdf) - Official, but too detailed white-paper

[AWS S3 documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)